# Enabling Backbone.emulateJSON() - POST issues

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, backbone.js

I am writing an app that uses a codeigniter backend custom REST service with a backbone front end. I am having trouble with creating a post(i.e. comment) in my db. I have read that enabling Backbone.emulateJSON() may be able to fix this. In summary I'm looking for where to include this line. A longer explanantion...

When I submit my form manually to create a new post the data is saved fine as expected. When I attempt the following in my postAddView...

```
 save: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        var postCollection = this.postCollection;

        var newPost = {
            message:"this is a post",
            author_id:"22",
            location:"New York"
        }

        postCollection.create(
            newPost,
            {
                wait: true,
                success: function(response){
                    console.log("successful" + response.toJSON);
                },
                error:function(err) {
                    console.log("this is the error "+ err.toJSON);
                }
            });

        return this;
     }
```

As as a result a new record is saved in my DB but no data is populated. Inspecting and comparing the networks in chrome shows that the ajax call from the backbone app submits it as 'request payload' vs. the form submission which is 'form data' (both are POSTS).

Based on my code above if anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated - however I'm also looking where to include backbone.emulateJSON() as many other posts have referenced this as a fix.

Answer (score 1):

emulateJSON is not a function

```
Backbone.emulateJSON = true
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateJSON